# Bibtex error - please use \mathaccent for accent

Tags: math-mode, bibtex, errors

I'm trying to use bibtex (.bib) for my reference and having following errors:

```
Please use \mathaccent for accents in math mode. Sadeghi, F., Levine, S.: (cad) $\^{}
Missing { inserted. Sadeghi, F., Levine, S.: (cad) $\^{}
You can't use `\spacefactor' in math mode. Sadeghi, F., Levine, S.: (cad) $\^{}
Missing } inserted. Sadeghi, F., Levine, S.: (cad) $\^{} 2$
```

The reference is this one:

```
Sadeghi, F., Levine, S.: (cad) $\^{} 2$ rl: Real single-image flight without a single real image.
```

[image]

I think `(cad) $\^{} 2$ rl` <<-- this part is causing the problem..

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: @campa I tried \hat as well, but I still get those errors. I added a captured image that describes what i want to print. please check it out..

Comment: OK, that's different, you want `CAD\textsuperscript{2}RL` or `CAD$^2$RL`. The macro `\^` is a text accent which puts a hat on a letter, and `\hat` is the math-mode accent. You are looking for a superscript.

Comment: @campa Wow!! `\textsuperscript ` works! Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: If you had wanted a math superscript 2 the markup would have been `$^{2}$` not `$\^{} 2$` or `$\hat{} 2$`  as you don't want a `^` accent

Comment: Are you using BibTeX? If so, what's the entry in the `.bib` file?